# Merge polygon pours in Altium Designer

Tags: pcb, altium, copper-pour

I need to know if there is a way to merge two or more polygon pours of the same type, in order to have only one. So two objects that become one. Is this possible?
Because anytime I need to redefine a polygon I do not want to start again if I only need to add and improve a little part of it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a function that lets you merge polygons.  At the same time, it's possible to achieve a similar effect while keeping the polygons distinct (without actually merging them).

1. Make the polygons pour over each-other. No isolating gap between polygons that are the same net.

Right-click on the polygon pour.  Select *Properties...* at the bottom of the context menu.

[image: Screenshot of Altium showing polygon pour properties]

2. Group the polygons.  Now they can be dragged around together.
   To adjust the shapes of individual polygons, you would have to temporarily break-up the union.  You can't adjust the polygons while they are inside of a union.

Select the polygons which you wish to group. Right-click.  Select *Unions → Create union from selected objects*.

[image: Screenshot of Altium showing the Union menu]

Answer (score 2):

As of Altium 17, this function is available:

- Select both polygons
- right click
- "Polygon Actions"
- "Combine selected polygons"

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot merge them, but of course you can change them.

Click SHIFT/CTRL and drag a vertex. It will take some time to get the hang of it, but once you understand how it works, it's quite comfortable. You can even switch corner mode by pressing Shift-Space during the modify operation.